# UIImagePicker set more than one image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, ibaction

I have several buttons. When either of the buttons are pressed it pops up and alertView asking the user to take a photo or select from the camera roll. Now the issue I am having is that I have 12 buttons and 12 UIImageViews. All buttons have there own action which pops the alert and allows the user to choose either of the options. Now in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method I pass the image from the camera or the camera roll to the first imageView. This all works fine, however if I want to select button 2 which fires the another alert with another tag i want to set imageView 2 and so on so on (Not replace imageView1). I need a way to distinguish in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo what imageView to set based on the button selection which popped the alert. Because at the moment the first image view is only getting set and reset if I choose another button which should set the corresponding image.

Heres the action for the button.

```
-(IBAction) addPhoto1:(id) sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image Source" message:@"Take a photo or select a previously taken photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Select Photo", nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 101;
    [alert release];

}
```

And alert `clickedButtonAtIndex`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    if (alert.tag == 101) {

        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            //Take photo
            [self performSelector:@selector(takePicture:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 2){
            //Camera roll
            [self performSelector:@selector(pictureAlbum:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] metadata:dict completionBlock:nil];


        if (addFirstImage.tag == 1001) {
            firstImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
           firstImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
           firstImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        }
        if (addSecondImage.tag == 1002) {            
           secondImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
           secondImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
           secondImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously this is not right whats the best way to set the correct imageViews image based on the button from the Alert that was originally pressed? (addFirstImage and addSecondImage are both buttons linked via IB)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use action's `sender' to 'remembers' which Button was pressed first ? 
Using IBOutletCollections, ordered with same indexes :

```
@property (...) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) allYourButtons;

@property (...) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) allYourImageViews;
// I suppose that both Collections objects have 'tags' (set in XIB file)
// a UIButton and the corresponding UIImageVIew have the SAME tag

@property (...) NSInteger clickedButtonIndex;

- (IBAction) imageViewWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    //keep a reference to the specific button that launched the action
    self.clickedButtonIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag]; 

    [self presentAlertViewForPictureChoice];
}
```

Then, you use `clickedButtonIndex` in your `UIAlertView` delegate method to find which UIImageVIew from `allYourImageViews` should have its image updated...

```
- (UIImageView *)imageToUpdateForSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex
{
    UIImageView *result = nil;
    for (UIImageView *imageView in self.allYourImageViews){
        if(imageView.tag == anIndex){
             result = imageView;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

**(EDIT)**
Ok, another way to associate a UIButton with a UIImageView is to create a subclass

```
// a new UIButton subclass

ButtonWithImageView : UIButton

@property (...) IBOutlet UIImageView *relatedImageView;

//IBOutlet enables you to directly link a Button with its imageVIew in your XIB

// in your controller

@property (...) ButtonWithImageView *selectedButton;


- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    ...
    self.selectedButton = (ButtonWithImageView *)sender;

}
```

Then all you have to do is edit `self.selectedButton.relatedImageView`

Comment: Humm not sure..I simply just need a way to know what button was pressed so that it sets the right image view in the didfinishpickingmediawithinfo. something like if (action1 was fired )then set image view one if (action2 was fired) then set image view 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to do this. Firstly I created an ivar int called myTag in interface file

```
int myTag;
```

I then tagged all my buttons with tag number i.e button1.tag = 1001 (to 1012 for my 12 buttons) in viewDidLoad,

I then created the one Action as opposed to 12 for each button. And connect all to this one action via IB.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton*)sender {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image Source" message:@"Take a photo or select a previously taken photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Select Photo", nil];
[alert show];
alert.tag = 101;
[alert release];

if (sender.tag == 1001){

    NSLog(@"You clicked button 1");
    myTag = 1001;

}

if (sender.tag == 1002){

    NSLog(@"You clicked button 2");
    myTag = 1002;
}
```

}

I then detect what button was pressed and pass an int value to myInt ivar

and then in my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I do this!

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] metadata:dict completionBlock:nil];

    if (myTag == 1001){


        firstImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        firstImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        firstImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    }

    if (myTag == 1002) {
        secondImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        secondImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        secondImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }





    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

All working perfectly! Many thanks for your help though!